# What is a phrase for testing for a certain result?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word or phrase for when someone is testing for a certain result thereby skewing his findings?

Comment: If you don't have luck here, try http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-physics-specific terminology. Depending on interpretations it is either about a psychology term or a statistical notion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not about physics and should be on english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Confirmation bias** might be what you're after.

From wiki:

> Confirmation bias [...] is the tendency of people to favor information that confirms their beliefs or hypotheses.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Comment: not exactly, the question doesn't  say that the someone is favouring to take only positive results